# Is 회춘 a legit Korean name?

Tags: names

I'm starting to learn Korean and I'm learning how to write my name in Hangeul.

The Chinese characters for my name is 懷春。

Based on these (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%87%B7 and https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%98%A5), the corresponding Korean name is 회춘.

Is that a legit Korean name? Does it sound odd or make people laugh when someone introduces themselves as 회춘?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

나쁜 이름은 아니지만 한국적인 이름은 아니에요.

한국 사람 입장에서 '회춘'이라는 이름을 들었을 때 드는 느낌:

- 나이가 엄청 많은 할머니 이름
- '성춘향'이 살던 고전 시대처럼 되게 옛날 사람 이름
- '오원춘'처럼 (별로 좋은 예는 아니지만) 중국계 한국인의 이름

HK Lee님이 말씀하신 것처럼 회춘했다는 말 같아서 웃기기도 하고요.

---

It could be a Korean name but not really a modern one.

How a name '회춘' sounds to me:

- Grandma's name. (aged 120+ y.o.)
- Someone from the classical era like when there actually were names like '성춘향'.
- Typical Chinese-Korean name. E.g. '오원춘' (Sorry, not the nicest example - that's just off the top of my head.)

And as HK Lee mentioned, it can be funny because it might also mean that an old man is rejuvenating(회춘).

Answer (score 4):

회춘하다 [回春] : 다시 젊어지다 grow younger

When we use another Chinese character 회(return, back to the
first position), 회춘 is healing sickness or being vivid. So when
someone obtain a young wife, we use frequently. Or when we see
someone's energy, we use : "He gets an energy" 그 사람 회춘했어.

Usually, **when we hear 회춘, then we think this word** so that it may
be funny.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be a good strategy to write as the pronunciation of your name `懷春` as `화이천`

Comment: Welcome to KSE.